# Get specific FB page access_token from /accounts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am wondering is there more elegant way to retrieve specific page access_token by his id   (I got huge list in /accounts which is from changes facebook did during the years)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the Page ID (e.g. `12345`) then you can make this Graph API call:

```
/v2.3/12345/?fields=access_token
```